# Find difference between two prices in percentage

Tags: python

I'm trying to divide the price range from the Lower Price to the Upper Price into the number of grids by an equal price ratio.

I need to find out what the ratio of each grid is in percentage.

My attempt:

```
import math

lower_price = 1.5
upper_price = 2.5
# grid_gap = 1 # Gap in percentage

total_grids = 10

grids = 0

ratio = math.pow(lower_price / upper_price, 1 / total_grids) * 100
print(ratio)

grids_list = []


# CALCULATE GRID
while True:
    if grids == total_grids:
        break
    else:
        grids += 1

        lower_price += (lower_price * ratio / 100)

        grids_list.append(f"{lower_price:0.3f}")

print(grids_list)
print(f"Total grids: {grids}")
```

My code below doesn't find out the correct ratio... to fit all the grids equally between the lower price and upper price. What's the error?

```
ratio = math.pow(lower_price / upper_price, 1 / total_grids) * 100
```

Output:

```
0.9502002165056764
['1.514', '1.529', '1.543', '1.558', '1.573', '1.588', '1.603', '1.618', '1.633', '1.649']
Total grids: 10
```

Comment: could you explain what you mean by equal price ratio?

Comment: You can use np.linspace() from numpy it has two required parameters, start and stop, which you can use to set the beginning and end of the range and third parameter can be used to set total_grids in your case. It returns an ndarray with equally spaced intervals between the start and stop values. e.g. np.linspace(lower_price , upper_price, total_grids).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ratio = (upper_price - lower_price) / (total_grids-1)
grids_list = [lower_price + v * ratio for v in range(total_grids)]
```

or you can use numpy library

```
import numpy as np
grids_list = np.linspace(lower_price, upper_price, total_grids)
```

to get the ratio, based on the `lower_price`, you could divide each item of the `grid_list` by the `lower_price` and then multiply by 100 to get the percentage.

```
ratio_list = [(price / lower_price)*100 for price in grids_list[1:]]
```

note: skipping first item because it is the lower price.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I checked, and I see that although they are equally distributed, the percentage between each grid is not equal and it's a step... I want like a fixed percentage between each grid, like 1% and 5%.

Comment: Like 1, 2, 4, 8...

Comment: you can choose to be equally percentage distributed or define the total grids you want between the range, not both. e.g 1.5 to 2.5, gap 10%. in the sixth number, the value will be above 2.5. so, if you want a fixed percentage between each grid, add X% to the last added number, but do not consider the hightest price as limit.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and show me how? I'm lost. :(